# No intellisense for angular 2 in eclipse Neon EE

Tags: html, angular, intellisense, eclipse-neon

I am not able to get any intellisense for my angular 2 in eclipse Neon EE version 4.6.0.
For example, if i use following code,

```
<ag-grid-angular style="width: 1000px; height: 110px;" class="ag-fresh"
             [rowData]="rowData"
             [columnDefs]="columnDefs"
             enableSorting
             enableFilter 
             enableColResize 
              >
```

This ag-grid does not provide any suggestions like what all i can use with this tag on hitting ctrl+space.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Eclipse won't do this unless you install a plugin for it  - you're really much better off using an editor that's designed for web stuff like VS Code or WebStorm. Eclipse isn't very good at the best of times, but for web development it's completely hopeless.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Can you specify which plugin do i need to install.

Comment: No idea, I'm afraid. I know there's a few on the Eclipse marketplace, but I've not used any of them.

Comment: Ok Thanks for your time!

Comment: Have you tried Angular Eclipse https://github.com/angelozerr/angular-eclipse/wiki/Installation-Update-Site ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what is "ag-grid-angular" but I can only advise you to use Visual Studio Code or Intellij Idea instead of Eclipse :)

Why ? Because Visual Studio Code is developped by Microsoft who also developed Typescript language. So it has an excellent support of this language.

Intellij Idea is also a great alternative but only the paid version support Typescript

Comment: I am using JAVA as backend. So Eclipse is more preferred tool than VS. So can't move to VS.

Comment: Why not you use both software (Eclipse and VSCode) ? Eclipse for the backend (Java) and VSCode for the frontend (Angular)

Comment: Thanks for reply. Is there any eclipse plugin for this which you know?

Comment: Nope sorry :P at least not to my knowledge

Comment: Have you tried https://github.com/angelozerr/angular-eclipse/wiki/Installation-Update-Site ?